# uninitialized constant LatexCurriculumVitae

Tags: ruby

I have a main module LatexCurriculumVitae:

```
module LatexCurriculumVitae
   LatexCurriculumVitae::Email.create_email_smtp('Heribert Hunz', 'saigkill@googlemail.com', 'Feger', 'male', 'no', 'yes')
end
```

Also a

```
module LatexCurriculumVitae::Email
   def self.create_email_smtp(contact, emailaddress, jobtitle, contact_sex, proactive, letter)
   [...]
end
```

If i'm running the main module i'm getting:

uninitialized constant LatexCurriculumVitae (NameError)

But wat happend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the method in a file with the modules nested:

```
module LatexCurriculumVitae
  module Email
    def self.create_email_smtp(contact, emailaddress, jobtitle, contact_sex, proactive, letter)
    [...]
    end
  end
end
```

Defining it with the double colon will fail because the outer module was not previously defined.

When you want to call the method, you don't need to wrap it in a module block:

```
LatexCurriculumVitae::Email.create_email_smtp('Heribert Hunz', 'saigkill@googlemail.com', 'Feger', 'male', 'no', 'yes')
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI

```
module B
  def self.print
    puts 'its outer B print'
  end
end

 module A
   def self.get_print_of_inner_B
     B.print
   end

   def self.get_print_of_outer_B
     ::B.print
   end
 end


 module A::B
  def self.print
    puts 'its inner B of A  print'
  end
 end
```

When you paste the code above in IRB, you get

```
2.2.1 :01 > A.get_print_of_inner_B
its inner B of A  print
 => nil 
2.2.1 :02 > A.get_print_of_outer_B
its outer B print
 => nil
```

**Conclusion:**
`::B.print` here, `::` is used to access the `constants` defined in global/outer scope rather than the current `module/class`